# Constraint/Index condition on ever pair of rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to force a condition that must be kept on each insert/update on a specific table.
Table's columns are: A | B | C and PK(A,B).
C is an Enum that has 3 different values - x,y,z.
The constraint that i'm trying to enforce upon INSERT/UPDATE is that for each pair of rows R1 and R2,
IF R1.B == R2.B THEN R1.C == x OR R2.C == x.

Tried enforcing it with Constrains and Indexes with no success.
Would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this partial unique index should do the trick:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tab (b) WHERE (c IS DISTINCT FROM x);
```